# Repairing a digital multimeter?

Tags: multimeter, repair

don't know if this is the right place to ask such a question but i'll try.
I opened up my DMM to check fuses. Now I would like to close it but before I can do this I have to put in the right place the range selector switch, but how can I do it? I don't know how the switch position relate to the position I see in the multimeter case..

Hope the explanation is clear.

Model is Finest 201

Comment: It's not clear to me. Cam you post pictures of the multimeter and internal connections? We can't tell you how the switch goes on your meter since you didn't even mention model number. Different multimeters have different selector switches.

Comment: I'll try to upload pictures, model is Finest 201

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just noticed that you're a new user. You can't upload pictures yet. Instead, post links in the comments and other users will edit the pictures into your post.

Comment: Take a 1MOhm resistor, turn the selector switch until you get a proper reading when connecting the resistor. Apply a low voltage (in series with a >1k resistor) on the volts range to double check.

Comment: @0x6d64 yes that did the trick! I used a similar method to what you described because I could help my search using some feedback from the display changing the dot location and giving a range indicator. Wasn't easy but I did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your multimeter appears as seen below.

If so:

**(1) Orientation fixed?:** I would have expected the dial to be able to be fitted in only one orientation on the shaft - check and see if this is the case.

**(2) Continuity beeper:**

(1) Connect a probe as shown by red line on photo below from COM socket to Volt-Ohm socket (2nd to right and right most sockets).

(2) Turn selector knob through one turn, stopping briefly at each location.
 Meter should produce high pitched sound when dial is set to "continuity beeper" position shown by arrow on photo.

**(3) Ohms:**  Similar to what OX6d64 said:

(1) Insert two probes in right two sockets as above and connect a low but non zero resistor between the probes. 1000 Ohms is probably good.

(2) Rotate dial while observing display.

When turning clockwise the Display should read appropriately for  1000 ohms  on the Ohms positions ie  (ignoring decimal point). Approximate reading in each case.

20M = 0
  2M = 0001  (or 0000 or 0002)
200K = 0010
 20K = 1100
  2K = 1000
 200 = 1999 or overload

It MAY  beep as above on the next range (continuity) but at 1000 Ohms probably not.

It should show about 1000 (probably) on the next range (diode test) dependimg on the test current (if 1mA).
  and then read zero on the next 22 positions (DCA, ACA, ACV, DCV)

The sudden change from 200 mV DC = 0 to a reading on the Ohms ranges will be clear. Note that the 20M range MAY not show a reading with 1K.

[image]

Comment: Yes that was similar to what I did! Orientation wasn't fixed, unluckily it had some possibilities :(